# LibGDX: Filtering a scaled TextureRegion

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine, textures, scaling

I have several objects with different textures for different states, so I am using a `TextureAtlas` made with TexturePacker, and resizing the `TextureRegion` where I need it. I have to resize because not only am I trying to support both 720p and 1080p, but some of my objects are tiles or cursors which resize based on the width and height of the board, as that can change in my game whereas the board will always occupy the same percentage of the screen.

With a `Texture`, I can just do this:

```
texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

However, when I am using a `TextureRegion` there is no option to set a filter. This results in these `TextureRegion`s resizing as sharp, blocky, and jagged. It isn't nice scaling and it doesn't seem to anti-alias at all.

This is pretty frustrating, because I'm bad enough at making graphics and now even when I like what I've made it looks crappy. What do I do to replicate the effect of `TextureFilter.Linear` using a `TextureRegion` instead of a `Texture`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can open your .atlas file and change the `filter` value to `Linear, Linear`. Or you can use `region.getTexture()` to get access to the Texture to which the region belongs, then call `setFilter(...)` on that.

Comment: To avoid manually changing the .altas file every time we pack images we can use this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you are packing using gdx-tools then you have to set the option

```
Settings settings = new Settings();
    settings.paddingX = 2;
    settings.paddingY = 2;
    settings.minWidth = 32;
    settings.minHeight = 32;
    settings.maxHeight = 1024;
    settings.maxWidth = 1024;
    settings.stripWhitespaceX = true;
    settings.stripWhitespaceY = true;
    settings.filterMag = TextureFilter.Nearest;
    settings.filterMin = TextureFilter.Nearest;
    settings.flattenPaths = true;

     TexturePacker2.process(settings, "input directory", "output directory","packName");

    System.out.println("PackTextures->main finished.");
```

or if you are using texture-packer-gui.jar then tick the checkbox for linear(min) and linear(max) and you are good to go...