# Libgdx and Android, How to make images resolution and density independence? How?

Tags: android, libgdx, game-engine, game-development

In my libgdx's game, I decided to use all space in each device so
in my screen I set dimension in this way:

```
stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
```

when I have to add an actor I resize it setting the width proportionally, so for example:

```
actor.setWidth(1/2f *  Gdx.graphics.getWidth())
stage.addActor(actor);
```

But it doesn't work well, because I use very big image (512x512) and each time it will be resizing setting width and height.
So for example if the images is 512x512 and resizing, then is not render well like a 128x128 image... Because it's too big... How can I render it correctly?

How I can make this resolution and density independence?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work well"?  Are you having a performance problem?  Or code maintenance issues?

Comment: This mean, It doesn't render well the images... So for example if the images is 512x512 and resizing, then is not render well like a 128x128 image... Because it's too big... How can I render it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To improve the quality of scaled images you can tweak the texture scaling algorithm.  See [LibGDX: Filtering a scaled TextureRegion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664924/libgdx-filtering-a-scaled-textureregion)